# UnicodeDecodeError while installing savReaderWriter using pip

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, installation

I've been working on reading .sav file. So, I need to install the savReaderWriter using pip. When I run

```
pip install savReaderWriter
```

on Windows 10, I get the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\fatihshen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 39: 
invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\fatihshen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\users\fatihshen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "c:\users\fatihshen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "c:\users\fatihshen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
spinner=spinner,
File "c:\users\fatihshen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
File "c:\users\fatihshen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 39: 
invalid continuation byte
```

I use Python 3.6.4 and pip 9.0.1.

Anyone any idea what is going on? I didn't encounter such an error while installing other packages. That is really strange. I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally solved this issue. It is definitely a bug of pip 9.0.1. So, I installed the new version (pip-10.0.0.dev0). But remember it is the one under development.

Here you go:

```
python -m pip install -U https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip
```

After re-running

```
pip install savReaderWriter
```

I no longer get that error. Happy End :)